# How to run through a number of functions until one returns False?

Tags: python

I'd like the `score` function to run the while loop until 1 of the "checks" returns False, and exit the loop if none return False. The "check" also returns a string that defines the message we'll display to user

```
def check_args(args, number_of_expected_args):
    if len(args) < number_of_expected_args:
        return False, 'cmd_missing_param'
    elif len(args) > number_of_expected_args:
        return False, 'cmd_extra_param'

def check_numbers(args, value):
    if args[value].isdigit() == False:
        return False, 'scores_invalid', 'var3'

def check_score(args, etc):
    if not blahblah....
        return False, 'response3'

def score(ctx, *args):

    test = []
    test[0], test[1] = True, 'Success'
    while test[0] == True:
        test = check_args(args, 4)
        test = check_numbers(args, 2)
        test = check_score(args, 3)
    
    print(test[1])

score(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Here is a snip of my working code. This is using discord.py to create a channel command bot, and the checks are to validate the arguments attached to the command.

There are 2 commands defined here, `score` and `schedule`, and both call the `check_test` function, although future commands may only need to run lesser amounts of the checks. So
I'm trying to move each individual check outside of my larger `check_test` function as I'll have many more checks to define and want to be able to call only specific ones

```
strings = {
    "english": {
        "cmd_missing_param": "Your submission is missing a parameter.",
        "cmd_extra_param": "Your submission has too many parameters.",
        "players_not_found": "Your submission user(s) {var1} cannot be found.",
        "scores_invalid": "Your submitted scores are not valid numbers.",
        "score_submitted": "Score successfully submitted",
        "schedule_submitted": "Schedule successfully submitted"
    }
}
    
async def reply(ctx, dict_string, arg1 = None, arg2 = None):
    # this function is to return a response to the user containing the success/fail message

    author = ctx.author.mention
    dict = strings['english']
    greeting = dict['greeting']
    response = dict[f'{dict_string}']

    return await ctx.reply(f"{greeting} {author}! {response}".format(var1 = arg1, var2 = arg2))

async def check_test(ctx, args, number_of_expected_args, args_players_index, args_scores_index, datetime_index, check_attachment):
    # this function is to perform a number of validations on our command args

    # check if command has expected number of args
    if args != '':
        if len(args) < number_of_expected_args:
            return False, 'cmd_missing_param'
        elif len(args) > number_of_expected_args:
            return False, 'cmd_extra_param'

    # check if the scores are valid numbers
    if args_scores_index != None:
        for each in args_scores_index:
            if args[each].isdigit() == False:
                return False, 'scores_invalid'
        
@client.command()
async def score(ctx, *args):
    # this command is to submit the score record for 2 players

    is_valid, response = await check_test(ctx, args, 4, [0, 1], [2, 3], None, '.w3g')
    if is_valid:
        player1, player2 = args[0], args[1]
        bot_message = await reply(ctx, 'score_submitted', player1, player2)
    else:
        await reply(ctx, response)
    
@client.command()
async def schedule(ctx, *args):
    is_valid, response = await check_test(ctx, args, 4, [0, 1], None, True, None)
    if is_valid: 
        player1, player2 = args[0], args[1]
        bot_message = await reply(ctx, 'schedule_submitted', player1, player2)
    else:
        await reply(ctx, response)
```

Comment: `any`. Also, `x == False` => `not x`, `x == True` => `x`

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm a bit new, I haven't heard of `any` so I'll look that up, but I'm not sure what the rest of your comment means?

Comment: `if args[value].isdigit() == False` can be written as `if not args[value].isdigit()`. Likely, `while test[0] == True:` should be just `while test[0]:`.

Comment: `any` and `all` are builtin Python functions. Both stop early, `any` on the first True, `all` - on the first False (but returns False then). Similar effect can be achieved by simple `and/or`: `check_args(args, 4) and check_numbers(...) and check_score(...)` will stop once any of these calls returns False

Comment: None of your code quite makes sense. These tests seem completely random and meaningless. What exactly are you testing? Your tests should return `True` for cases where the "tests" pass. Why do you only test if `args[2]` is a number? You also say you want to exit the loop if none return `False`, but you also say that the loop should run until one of the "checks" returns `False`... in which case you simply need to `break` if a test returns `False`... but also there's no reason for a `while` loop at all here.

Comment: This really should be written as a single "check" function that tests everything in the order you want things tested, and using `raise` with custom errors if any one test fails.

Comment: A loop? Why do you want to repeat the exact same checks over and over again?

Comment: The tests are meaningless because it's example code..
I thought to use a while loop to avoid multiple if..else statements as I'm trying to refractor my functions from what I currently have which is a single "check" function as you describe

Comment: I only need to run the checks once, but also don't want to run unnecessary checks, so I guess I'm not sure how to appropriately capture that and break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how you might write a validation function for `args`:

```py
expected_number_of_args = 5


def validate_score_args(args):
    # example: test that exactly 'expected_number_of_args' were passed
    n = len(args)
    if n != expected_number_of_args:
        raise ValueError(f"Expected {expected_number_of_args} args, but got {n}.")

    # example: make sure all args are numeric
    if not all(type(arg) in {int, float} for arg in args):
        raise TypeError(f"Expected all arguments to be numeric.")

    # example: if the above test passed, then check values
    if not all(arg > 0 for arg in args):
        raise ValueError(f"Expected all arguments to be positive.")

    # and so on


def score(ctx, *args):
    try:
        validate_score_args(args)
    except (ValueError, TypeError) as err:
        # Do something about error instead of 're-raising' it, but for now:
        raise err
    
    # If args were valid, then use them:
    return sum(args)
```

Add any number of "tests" to `validate_score_args()`. They'll run in order from top to bottom, and if any test fails, none of the following tests will run.

However, I'd recommend always running all your tests, and then "collecting" all the errors and doing something with them (like displaying them to the user) so that the user can see everything they did wrong at once instead of having to play whack-a-mole, fixing one bug at a time.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my original post with more info and a snippet of my current code. It's quite similar to what you have here, and I'm trying to avoid this as my single check function is getting very long

Comment: So separate each check into its own named function, and call each function to run each test. You can `catch` errors raised by the testing functions, and access the error message associated with the error object.

The code you posted in your update is really messy and littered with serious architectural problems and I want to go to bed, so for now I'm going to leave my answer untouched. The takeaway is that you should be using `try`, `catch` and `raise` to do your checks as it'll simplify your error messaging.

Comment: Please see the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. Got it working with this. Can you share what sort of architectural problems I have?